# Man page with preserved text decorations, proportional text and fixed-width code

Tags: man, text-formatting

How can I get contents of a man page without the text being wrapped around column 80 or so? I'd prefer the output to have proper formatting, line bolding, underscores, fixed-width font for examples etc.

However, all the command-line utilities and online man page resources provide either wrapped (http://linux.die.net) or un-formatted (`man mmap | col -bx > mmap.txt`), or improperly formatted (`man -t mmap | ps2pdf - mmap.pdf`) versions.

How can I get the properly formatted unwrapped text from a man page to be used for further booklet printing?

Comment: Look at the link I posted: `man -P cat command_name`.

Comment: @slm that won't do the formatting, the OP wants to have his cake and eat it, both markup and unwrapped. `man -P cat` won't do it and neither will any of the other answers on the linked Q.

Comment: Change the pager to whatever you want. Do this instead to get the formatting + wrapping: `man -P less command_name`. Is this not what you want?

Comment: Out of interest, what is "improperly formatted" about the ps2pdf output?  Do you mean you want to save it to a file for later viewing on a screen of any size?  Or you want to make `man` look better when you run it on a large screen?

Comment: @Mikel: "Improperly" means that the code sample is rendered using the same proportional font as the main text. Looking at the proportional source code has quite an acid-in-the-eyes effect for me, which I find "improper".

Comment: Hmm.  Well, if you look at the input file, e.g. `/usr/share/man/man2/mmap.2.gz`, you'll notice there's not a lot of markup to help tell what's English prose, and what's a code sample.    How would you tell the difference?

Comment: I'm no pro at markup reading, but the `man2html` definitely distinguish English prose from source code in "EXAMPLE" section and renders it the correct way. Maybe th `.nf` markup?

Comment: @mbaitoff code sample being rendered using proportional font is more likely issue of your formatter. For example I'm sitting at two computers ATM with different Linux distributions and on one `man2html` formats it flawlessly while on the other one it has issues with code sample (single line breaks are not interpreted verbatim).

Comment: @mbaitoff Good point.  So what's missing in the `man2html` output?  It's soft wrapped, but that doesn't matter in HTML: only tags such as `<p>` and `<br>` cause actual line breaks.

Comment: @Mikel Looks like the `man2html` is the most appropriate solution to my question, and I marked the corresponding answer as accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have not specified your desired output format but from the things you've tried, it looks like you're not picky. This will produce correctly formatted, unwrapped html but it needs to be run on the actual man page file.

So, first locate the man file you're interested in:

```
$ man -w mmap
/usr/share/man/man2/mmap.2.gz
```

Them, run `man2html` on it:

```
man2html /usr/share/man/man2/mmap2.2.gz > mmap.html
```

Or, simply

```
zcat $(man -w mmap) | man2html > mmap.html
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

`man2html` was available in the Debian repository, I installed it with `sudo apt-get install man2html`.

<del>Once you have it in HTML, you can translate to other formats easily enough:</del> Actually, these won't work, they'll wrap the line automatically again.

```
man2html /usr/share/man/man1/grep.1.gz | html2ps > grep.ps
man2html /usr/share/man/man1/grep.1.gz | html2ps | ps2pdf14 - grep.man.pdf
```

`

Answer (score 3):

You can skip installing `man2html` and use `groff` to do the HTML conversion as well.

```
$ man -w netstat | xargs zcat | groff -T html -man > netstat.html
```

Then use `elinks` or some terminal web browser to view them.

```
$ elinks netstat.html
```

[image: ss of elinks]

You can skip generating a file entirely if you use `lynx` as your web browser, which has a `-stdin` feature for reading in HTML.

```
$  man -w netstat | xargs zcat | groff -T html -man | lynx -stdin
```

[image: ss of lynx]

Answer (score 3):

Depending on exactly what you want the output to look like, and what system you're on, here's some things that could be useful.

1. Setting line length via the `.ll` macro
2. Setting left justification instead of block justification `.ad l`
3. Using `man -Tutf8` to tell `man` to output terminal formatting, even when redirecting stdout.

On my system, I can achieve this by modifying `/usr/share/groff/current/tmac/tty.tmac` and running `man -Tutf8`.

But you said you wanted text in a proportional font but code in a fixed-width font.  Most terminals don't have the ability to switch between different fonts, and man pages don't carry any markup to say what's code and what human language.  So your best bet is to find a document in another format for display in a browser or graphical viewer.

Probably the best two places for such documentation are

- [The POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/)
- [The GNU libc docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/)

But there are others, depending on the command or function you're trying to look up.

Comment: Forgot to say that I need the formatted unwrapped output for  printing purposes. Dealing with macros and manual markup is not quite what I need.

Comment: @mbaitoff, I'm quite certain that your printer is not a ticker tape.  So you can't print *unwrapped* text no matter what you do.  It has to get wrapped somewhere, whether your printer driver does it, your PDF converter, or your source text file.

Comment: I would suggest you play with printing from a terminal set to various widths, and see which gives the best results on the actual medium.  It shouldn't be too hard to [hack](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/meaning-of-hack.html) your problem that way.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell if you want some "special" formatting that's different from standard formatting that's done using [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code):

> I'd prefer the output to have ***proper*** formatting, line bolding,
> underscores, fixed-width font for examples etc.

(does "proper just mean "the normal way that `man` does it"?)

But... I will answer with regards to this part of your question:

> How can I get contents of a man page without the text being wrapped
> around column 80 or so?

Just use:

```bsh
MANWIDTH=9999 man mmap > mmap.txt
```

or:

```
COLUMNS=9999 man mmap > mmap.txt
```

If you need to do something fancier, you can use `groff` directly, but it doesn't seem to respect the `COLUMNS` variable.  This [awesome answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18491/464414) provided a solution: use the arguments `-rLL <number>` and `-rLT <number>` to `groff` (apparently undocumented, but `man` itself uses them).

For example, I use the following function to dump `man` pages to plain-text (intentionally disabling the formatting that you want to preserve, but just as an example):

```bsh
man2txt() {
    groff -t -e -mandoc -Tascii -a -rLL=9999 -rLT=9999 "$(man -w "${1}")"
}
```

You could remove the `-Tascii -a` and add in whatever `groff` options you want, if you do in fact want to do anything special in that regard.