# How to inform man about number of columns in non interactive mode?

Tags: man

I'm running man in non interactive mode from bash and I'm displaying the result on the webpage. I have number of character per line calculated on a page, how can I inform the man command about number of characters per line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `man` on Linux to generate the output (e.g. `man command > output-file`) then you can set MANWIDTH to the value you'd like.

```
MANWIDTH=120 man tr > tr.txt
```

Comment: see also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18491/117549 for telling `groff` how to do it by hand.